# How can I use a class instead of creating multiple methods?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am currently working on a WinForms application where I want the user to click on a button and then change the buttons text. I have 11 buttons and setting up methods for `MouseUp`, `MouseDown`, `Click` for each of those buttons would result in a lot of work and repetitions of very similar code.

I have made a class, but don't know to address the button that the user clicked.

```
public class AddButton 
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Count++;
            ?ProductButton?.Text = Count + " Added";
        }
    }
```

Click [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hqcuu5BsMM1WQ4k5c-yXRIAy3RcwfwkF) link to download the full WinForms project if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it:

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
b.BackColor = DashboardColors.EM_EditingTextBoxBackground;
b.Text = "Save";
```

Cast 'sender' as its appropriate type, then you can work with it normally.

This should work:

```
public class AddButton 
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddButton ab = (AddButton)sender;

        Count++;
        ab.Text = Count + " Added";
    }
}
```

If AddButton is derived from Button-

```
public class AddButton : Button
```

Since 'Text' is a property of the base class; casting sender as a (Button) should also work.

Comment: How do you set up that the button is an instance of the `AddButton` class?

Comment: `public class AddButton 
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddButton ab = (AddButton)sender;

            Count++;
            ab.Text = Count + " Added";
        }
    }`

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so many questions, but I can't find a way to actually call the `Button_Click` method. Do I have to call it inside of the automatically generated WinForms one? That would still result in having to write down 33 different methods. I am hoping for a possibilty to just let inheritance do the job for all those functions... EDIT: Should I just post a new question? my original question was answered.

Comment: @hjknvcaesdbuihjase is AddButton a class derived from button?

If it is- in the AddButton constructor assign the click handler method to its event...

`public AddButton()
{
    this.click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click);
}`

If not it gets more complex.  Without knowing more about what you are doing I can't be more specific.